# Soloing using the G Major and A Minor Arpeggio

Tags: lead-guitar

I am learning how to solo using chord tones. As of now I am experimenting with the **G Major Triad** and the **A Minor Triad**. I play through the notes then resolve on one of the ***G Major Chord tones***. How come when I play my "solo" it doesn't sound right, like my phrases don't sound like an actual solo. It could all be in my head, but to be specific I'm going to play through my sequence and upload a tab to show what can be improved upon, so I can finally write solos that make sense. I think I'm supposed to connect my phrases, but Jimmy Page didn't do that in Whole Lotta Love lol and his phrases sounded like they went well together without connecting them. It sounded like a solo and not like the music I hear in Kindergarten Music class. It also doesn't sound when I **pause** between the **[image: two phrases]** I wrote.

Comment: Trouble with a lot of tab (and this one) is that we get no sense of the timing of your phrases, which is just as important as the actual notes themselves.

Comment: The picture only shows a series of pitches, it doesn't really say anything about your playing. A huge number of different melodies can be made from those pitches, even if played in the exact same order. What are you playing those over, when, how? Do you play accurately in time? What are your rhythmic ideas like? What chords do your notes create when combined with the rest of the music? Is your pulse in sync with the music? An imprecise pulse can even make a line unidentifiable as a phrase, IMO. And random pitches, played accurately and convincingly with a rhythmic idea can sound like a phrase.

Comment: I had another answer to this question. Where did it go?

Comment: It was removed by the author. Maybe he realized that it's just a lot of speculation, not knowing what kind of phrases you're trying to play, when and over what, and how you succeed in playing them. What your ideas are and how you execute them. The problem could be many things, we don't know. It could be the ideas, or their execution, or both. Your picture is essentially just a pitch list, it does not specify a phrase, nor how and where you play it. IMO, an audio recording would be best, but this site doesn't really support actual music i.e. sound, only various cumbersome descriptions of music.